# defining arrays in android studio

Tags: java

this is my first question.
I have problem with defining arrays in android studio.
this is piece of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;

//The code from input.
private String code;
//size of interpreting memory.
public static final int memorySize=3000;
//Memory of system for interpreting.
private byte memory[3000];
```

it's compiler's error:

```
Main.java:43: error: ']' expected
private int blockStack[blockStack_size];
                       ^
Main.java:43: error: illegal start of type
    private int blockStack[blockStack_size];
                                      ^
Main.java:43: error: <identifier> expected
    private int blockStack[blockStack_size];
                                       ^
Main.java:43: error: ';' expected
    private int blockStack[blockStack_size];
                                        ^
```

i also changed "private" to "private static", "public static", "public" and also removed that identifier, but always the same error.

Comment: `byte[] memory = new byte[3000];` The issue has nothing to do with Android or Android Studio - you just aren't using basic valid java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Please learn Java from basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got some confusion on how to declare and initialize arrays in Java. A quick overview:

- To declare an array of `Type`, you write `Type[]`.
- When initializing an array, you write `new Type[size]` (where size is the number of elements the array can hold.

So it looks like you probably want to write

```
private byte[] memory = new byte[3000];
```

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html